# nmap -sn and -sL produce different results for the same host

Tags: nmap

When I scan the whole network it shows 3 hosts are up:

```
pi@Pi /Z $ nmap -sn 192.168.0.0/24

Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-09-09 00:48 EDT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.100
Host is up (0.14s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.101
Host is up (0.00081s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.251
Host is up (0.0031s latency).
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (3 hosts up) scanned in 36.64 seconds
```

But when I target a specific host (immediately before and after), it says it's not up:

```
pi@Pi /Z $ sudo nmap -sL 192.168.0.100

Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-09-09 00:47 EDT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.100
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 0.03 seconds
```

Any explanation for the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the manual page for `nmap`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nmap):

> -sL: List Scan - simply list targets to scan
>
> -sn: Ping Scan - disable port scan

The sentence `(0 hosts up)` in the output of `nmap -sL` simply means that no replies were received from the host, which is not surprising since no packet was sent, just the IP listed.

To double-check this, try

```
   nmap -sL 192.168.0.0/24
```

You will simply see the list of addresses corresponding to the subnet `192.168.0.0./24`. The `-sL` flag is basically just a way to list subnets, occasionally difficult ones like `192.168.17.123/27`.